# How can I use different views in one MapView

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit

How can I use different views in one MapView.I mean if I use the

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
```

Then all the annotation View will be the same in one Mapview.
What I mean is how can I set different View style(including Images etc.) in One MapView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different view. For example,

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    if ... {
        // Marker annotation
        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView?.canShowCallout = true
            pinView?.isDraggable = true

            let rightButton: AnyObject! = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure)
            pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton as? UIView
        }
        else {
            pinView?.annotation = annotation
        }
        return pinView
    } else if ... {
        // Image annotation
        let reuseId = "image"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView?.canShowCallout = true
            pinView?.image = UIImage(named: "Laugh")

            let rightButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure)
            pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton
        }
        else {
            pinView?.annotation = annotation
        }

        return pinView
    }
}
```